# displaying array items to textbox separated by a comma and ended by a ")"

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a listbox that is dynamically added from a treeview, and what I wanted to do is to put the items in the listbox into an array, then display the item/s of the array(separated by a comma(if items > 1) and ended by a ")") in a textbox. So far, I've only achieved the separation by a comma.
Can someone help me out? Below is my code

```
Public Sub Array()
    Dim LboxItems As Integer = listbox.Items.Count
    Dim countBox As Integer = LboxItems - 1
    ReDim arrayTest(LboxItems)
    For item = 0 To countBox
        arrayTest(item) = listbox.Items(item).ToString
        txtboxOut = String.Join(", ", arrayTest)
    Next
    txtboxOut.Text = outMun
    If LboxItems = 0 Then
        Array.Clear(arrayMTest, 0, arrayMTest.Length)
        txtOut.Text = arrayTest(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

txtboxOut should be displaying this:

if array items > 1

```
<item0>, <item1>, ... , <itemN>)
```

if array items = 1

```
<item0>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are not clear in your posted code:

```
txtboxOut.Text = outMun
```

What is outMun, and where is it assigned?  Also, what is `arrayMTest` and why are you clearing it when you don't appear to be doing anything with it?

Finally, the following line of code:

```
txtboxOut = String.Join(", ", arrayTest)
```

Should be called once, after the array is built.  And I think it should be `txtboxOut.Text` as well.

Having said all of that, the following code snippet should accomplish what you are looking for (note that nowhere in your code do you appear to be adding `)` to the end of the string, which is why you're not seeing it.

```
Public Sub Array()

    If listbox.Items.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arrayTest(listbox.Items.Count)

        For item = 0 to listbox.Items.Count - 1

            arrayTest(item) = listbox.Items(item).ToString()
        Next

        txtboxOut.Text = String.Join(", ", arrayTest) + ")"
    Else
        txtboxOut.Text = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

In a nutshell, the above code checks to see if there are any items in the ListBox.  If there are, it loops through the Items collection and adds each item to `arrayTest`.  Once the loop is finished, it uses `String.Join` to make the comma-separated list and adds ")" to the end.

If there are no items in the ListBox, it assigns an empty string to the TextBox.

This is one way to do this - there are others, some of which don't even use an array.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Those variables are typographic errors. I forgot to delete the 'txtboxOut.Text=outMun' line, the 'arrayMtest' is the 'arrayTest', I forgot to erase "M". 
Anyways, what are the other ways you are referring to? Can you site some examples?